# How do you find nonterminating cycles in a 2D vector field?

Tags: vector, cycle, orbital-mechanics

I have a finitely-sized 2D vector field. What I want is to find any "cycles" in this field - that is, if this field represented the flow of a fluid, and you placed an object on one of these cycles, the object would go around and around and would never come to rest. I think I've found some scholarly mathematical articles about this problem, but they're so far over my head that I can't make any sense of them. Is there a standard algorithm for finding such cycles?

Why do I want to find cycles like this? I'm considering making a 2D platformer that has a similar concept to Super Mario Galaxy, in that there will be several small gravitating bodies that the player can jump between and walk on, rather than a single global gravity vector. The gravity field for the static bodies would be computed statically during level editing. I don't really *have* to solve this problem, but it would be a very nice tool for detecting unescapable gravity loops in the level editor rather than having to discover them through playtesting.

Comment: I'd learn what you need to make, *then* try to implement it. You won't get very far if you have no practice in the field whatsoever...

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to imagine a "gravity field" that contains cycles. However, the trajectory of the player might be cyclic. We call this "orbit."

An easy solution might be to include a small amount of friction or dampening to ensure that orbits decay.

A less tractable solution: if the space is discrete, then you can test each state (position,velocity) and check if the player ever re-visits the same state. Note that this would also require a finite number of legal velocity values.

From a usability perspective, giving the player some means of propulsion would also be a nice way to solve the problem.

Comment: Goddammit Yann I can't get away from you.